# Const function arguments in java?

Tags: java, const-correctness

Is there a way to achive something similar to C++'s `const` in Java? Specifically, I have a function like

```
private static Vector2 sum(Vector2 vec1, Vector2 vec2) {
    return vec1.cpy().add(vec2);
}
```

and I want to

1. make clear in the signature that it doesn't modify it's arguments,
   and
2. enforce that it doesn't modify it's arguments (preferably at compile time, but inserting runtime assertions would also be OK).

Now I know that java is strictly pass-by-reference (I'm just teasing, I know [it is pass-by-value or rather pass-by-copying-a-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) of course). What I mean is that in Java, when you call a method, the reference is copied, but that reference points to the same object contents. If a class has public fields or setters, a called method can always modify the contents of a passed object. Is there any e.g. annotation like `@NotNull` or tool to prevent this? I just found the JetBrains annotations like `@Contract(pure = true)`, but I don't think they provide any checking.

Comment: You can add `final` to the parameter, but this will only prevent a initialisation of those, you still can call method and setter modifying the content of your `Vector`. If you need the restrict the access to those, you might need to create a immutable class hiding the `Vector`. Basicly it will write every methods to prevent update (hiding the setter and limit the getter to primitive values)

Answer (score 4):

You can not guarantee that method won't change the parameters. If you want to avoid changing the object, you should make it immutable. You can use some wrapper classes to be passed inside, without provided setters. Or you can make your setters package-local and use some access helper classes in the same package if you need to call some package-local method.

Comment: Careful to the getters, this might return a POJO that could be updated ;) we basicly add the same idea

Comment: @AxelH yeah, it is details of implementation, i just provided a general way  :)

Answer (score 3):

In Java the only way to do this is to have a read only interface as well as a mutable one.  This isn't easy to maintain and a `const` would be much nicer, but it's not available. You can write

```
interface ReadOnlyVector<T> {
    int size();
    // getter methods
    T get(int n);

    default ReadOnlyVector<T> add(ReadOnlyVector<T> v) { 
        // add two vectors and create a new one.
    }
}

interface Vector<T> extends ReadOnlyVector<T> {
    // mutating methods.
    void add(T t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `final` to the parameter, but this will only prevent a initialisation of those, you still can call method and setter modifying the content of your `Vector`.

If you need the restrict the access to those, you might need to create a immutable class hiding the `Vector`, **a wrapper**. Basicly it will redirect only the methods that prevent any update by hiding the setter and limit the getter to primitive values, returning an instance give a possibility to change a value in it.

Of course, there is also some drastic solution, you could **clone** the Vector and his content. Keeping the instances safe even if someone try to update some values. This will only be a problem during this call, using wrong values but will keep the original instances unchanged.

Or you could use both solution, creating a wrapper that return cloned instance (just need to provide a get(int index) that return a clone). This solution is a compromise between memory consumption (cloning only needed instance) and restrictive getter.